# I want to create a dynamic variable and use it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create and use a dynamic variable in Python for the first time.

```
for i in range(0,len(test_data)):
     globals()["test_list_{}".format(test_data[i])]=[]
     globals()["test_calculation_{}".format(test_data[i])]=0
```

First, I created test_list_number and test_calculation_number as global variables.

Then I want to use this in for and use it for calculations.
The code I wrote here was made by simplifying the code I'm going to use.

How do I change the numbers in the two for statements below?

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb8Ap.png)

--------------Below is a code example. -------------

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X=list(np.random.random(100)*100)
Y=list(np.random.random(100)*100)

test_data= [2,5,7,8]

test_dict={(i,j):np.hypot(X[i]-X[j],Y[i]-Y[j]) for i in range(0,100) for j in range(0,100)}



test_df_data2={
    'index' : [1,2,3],
    'data1' : [3,5,6],
    'data2' : [2,5,6]
}



test_df_data5={
    'index' : [1,2,3],
    'data1' : [8,3,1],
    'data2' : [3,2,7]
}

test_df_2  =pd.DataFrame(test_df_data2)
test_df_5  =pd.DataFrame(test_df_data5)


for i in range(0,len(test_data)):
    globals()["test_list_{}".format(test_data[i])]=[]
    globals()["test_calculation_{}".format(test_data[i])]=0

    
    
for i in range(0, len(test_df_2     )  ):
    test_list_2       .append((test_df_2   .data1[i],test_df_2     .data2      [i]))

for i in range(len(test_list_2    )):
    test_calculation_2    = test_calculation_2     + test_dict[test_list_2       [i] ]

    
print( test_calculation_2)
```

Comment: Use a dictionary with the "dynamic variable" names as your keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Have found anything in Python, numpy or pandas docs that talks about "dynamic variable".  I don't recall anything with that name, though I can guess what you are trying to do.  You are better off using documented, accepted practices, as opposed to importing some concept from another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, **do not do this!**

It is widely accepted to be a bad practice (see [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458691/is-it-a-good-idea-to-dynamically-create-variables)). You have a high risk of doing something difficult to debug, to overwrite existing variables, or to use the wrong namespace. In addition there are [eventual pitfalls and lack of robust methods to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable/8028772).

**Use a container instead.**
You will have a shorter, cleaner, and easier to debug code.

Dictionaries are ideal for this:

```
# initialize
my_dfs = {}

# computation
for i in …:
    my_dfs[f'df_computation_{i}'] = …

# access
my_dfs['df_computation_42']
```

Comment: I used the wrong method because I didn't study enough. thank you for telling me. I'll do ask before asking another question.

Comment: @Soo don't feel bad, many want to do this. It feels like a attractive/natural way to handle multiple datasets. I think it's mostly with experience that your acquire enough abstraction to realize this is not ideal/needed.