# traversing graph and creating dynamic variable

Tags: for-loop, graph, networkx

I have a simple graph with few nodes and these nodes have attributes such as "type" and "demand".

```
def mygraph():
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from([("N1", {"type":"parent","demand": 10}),
    ("N2"{"type":"parent","demand": 12}),
    ("N3", {"type":"parent","demand": 25}), 
    ("S1", {"type":"server","demand": 12}), 
    ("S2,{"type":"server","demand": 20})])
```

I am passing this graph to another function in pyomo library. The dummy pyomo function is as follows:

```
def mymodel():
    g=mygraph()
    **VARIABLES**
    model.const1 = Constraint(my constraint1)
    model.const2 = Constraint(my constraint2)
    model.obj1 = Objective(my objective)
    status = SolverFactory('glpk')
    results = status.solve(model)
    assert_optimal_termination(results)
    model.display()
mymodel()
```

I am trying to:

1. In graph function **mygraph():**, I need to find the total number of nodes in the graph G with attribute type==parent.
2. In pyomo function **mymodel():**, I need to create the number new of **VARIABLES** equal to the number of nodes with attribute type==parent. So in the case above, my program must create 3 new variables, since 3 nodes have attribute type==parent in my graph function. The values of these newly created variables will be accessed from the demand attribute of the same node thus, it should be something like this;

```
new_var1=demand of node1 (i.e., node1_demand=10 in this case)
new_var2=demand of node2 (i.e., node2_demand=12)
new_var3=demand of node3 (i.e., node2_demand=25)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can loop over the nodes:

```
sum(1 for n,attr in G.nodes(data=True) if attr['type']=='parent')
# 3

# or to get all types
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(attr['type'] for n,attr in G.nodes(data=True))
# {'parent': 3, 'server': 2}
c['parent']
# 3
c['server']
# 2
```

For the second part (which also gives you the answer of the first part of you check the length):

```
{n: attr['demand'] for n,attr in G.nodes(data=True) if attr['type']=='parent'}

# or
[attr['demand'] for n,attr in G.nodes(data=True) if attr['type']=='parent']
```

Output:

```
{'N1': 10, 'N2': 12, 'N3': 25}

# or
[10, 12, 25]
```

##### instanciating attributes

```
def mymodel():
    g = mygraph()
    nodes = [attr['demand']
             for n,attr in G.nodes(data=True)
             if attr['type']=='parent']

    # initialize model?

    for i,n in enumerate(nodes, start=1):
        setattr(model, f'const{1}', Constraint(something with n))
    
    # ...
```

Comment: Dear Mozway! Thank you for your detailed response. I guess I didn't express my second part well, let me re-explain it.
A for loop will run till the number of times we have parent nodes and it will create dynamic variables such as create new variable1=demandvalue of node1, create new variable2=demandvalue of node2 and so on. This creation of variables and assignment of values will go till the number of the parent nodes.

Comment: @WaqasSwati I'm sorry but it's unclear. Why do you need a loop? Why dynamic variables? Can't you iterate over the values of the second part directly? Please provide context and a description of what you want to achieve. [Generating variables dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) is [never a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458691/is-it-a-good-idea-to-dynamically-create-variables).

Comment: Thank you @Mozway, I cannot disagree with what you wrote earlier. Actually, I'm making a graph in networkx, and later this graph will be used by a function in the Pyomo library. So I'll be passing the networkx graph to a pyomo function. In the pyomo function, I need to create new variables that are equivalent to the nodes in my graph with the parent attribute, and their values will be equal to their demands attribute.

Comment: It might be worth providing a minimal example of how you generate one graph with a defined set of nodes, then we can maybe see how to generalize?

Comment: I appreciate your time @mozway. I am grateful; I attempted to provide more information in the query. I hope that makes sense.